# How do you unset MAILTO in crontab?

Tags: linux, cron

As the documentation for [crontab](http://www.gsp.com/cgi-bin/man.cgi?section=5&topic=crontab) explains, if `MAILTO` is not set then output goes to the owner of the cron, if `MAILTO` is set and not empty, it says where mail should go, and if it is set and empty, no mail is set.

Is there any way to unset environment variables like `MAILTO` in cron after it has already been set to something?  I already tried the obvious `unset MAILTO` and `MAILTO=` but `crontab -e` does not accept those.

I have a workaround (make sure that everything that I want default mailing behavior comes before the original).  However I'm writing a script to write cron jobs, and it would be nice to be able to set/unset `MAILTO` without having to reorder commands.

If it matters, this will be running on a Linux system under Vixie cron.

*Edit:* Clarification.  I want jobs to either get mailed to the owner or to a user named in a `MAILTO`.  I don't want the behavior that `MAILTO=''` causes where jobs get mailed to nobody at all.

Comment: Ever figure this out?

Comment: @bpeikes Nope.  I had to do the workaround.

Comment: What was the workaround?

Comment: @bpeikes As the question says, I reordered the cron entries to have everything that needed an unset MAILTO come first.

Comment: As you say, if MAILTO is not set, output goes to the owner. Can you just not use MAILTO="owner" when you want that behaviour?

Comment: @BobbyJack That will attempt to send messages to a user named owner.  Which is almost certainly not what you want.

Comment: @btilly Sure — you should replace "owner" with the username of the cron, sorry I thought that was obvious

Comment: @BobbyJack I was autogenerating a cron with a mix of owners, and a mix of different email behaviors.  Better yet, the cron itself had a mix of preconfigured jobs, and user configured jobs.  This was in a shared hosting environment.  There are multiple ways to skin the cat, and I chose to reorder entries.

Answer (score 0):

Do not believe there is anyway to unset it: you might want to just pipe the output of the commands you don't want emailed into `/dev/null`.